# Replacing the <ion-select> button texts by icons

Tags: ionic-framework, icons, ion-select

I am looking for a way to replace the placeholder texts in an ion-select action sheet with icons instead of simple text.

[image]

Now, I know the texts can be changed by adding ‘okText’ and ‘cancelText’ to the HTML:

```
<ion-select multiple="true" [(ngModel)]="selectedGenres" (ionChange)="filterByGenre()" okText="Okido!" cancelText="Nah, whatever..">
        <ion-option *ngFor="let genre of genreList" value="{{genre}}">{{genre}}</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

But what would be the best ways to add icons to those buttons?

For instance, I would like to replace the OK text with e.g. ‘ion-android-checkbox-blank’ icon and CANCEL text with e.g. ‘ion-android-close’ icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly possible. You can use ionic [modal](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/modal/ModalController/) to create your own selection list with your own buttons.

As an alternative, you may want to test emojis like ❌ and ✔️, but they will look different from device to device.

Comment: Thanks, I'll go with this solution for the time being. I will later on create my own selection list.